# using loader with worker

Tags: actionscript-3, worker

I want to load image from worker, but i get this error :

> *** Security Sandbox Violation *** Connection to file:///C|/Users/Mudinho/Documents/projetos/as3/Engine/bin/TileSet/testeTileSet.png
>   halted - not permitted from
>   file:///C|/Users/Mudinho/Documents/projetos/as3/Engine/bin/Engine.swf
>   -- Remote SWFs may not access local files.
>
> Worker 2: [Fault] exception, information=SecurityError: Error #2148:
>   SWF file
>   file:///C|/Users/Mudinho/Documents/projetos/as3/Engine/bin/Engine.swf
>   cannot access local resource
>   file:///C|/Users/Mudinho/Documents/projetos/as3/Engine/bin/TileSet/testeTileSet.png.
>   Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access
>   local resources.

i already put the -use-network=false in compiler options, set "Use Network Services" to false, 
not running the swf via browser, the debug(Security.sandboxType); print remote

here is my worker code

```
package {
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.system.MessageChannel;
    import flash.system.Security;
    import flash.system.Worker;
    import flash.system.WorkerDomain;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import starling.core.Starling;
    import starling.textures.Texture;
    import starling.utils.AssetManager;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author
     */

    public class SlaveWorker extends Sprite {
        private var miso:MessageChannel;
        private var mosi:MessageChannel;
        private var byteArray:ByteArray;
        //private var asset:AssetManager;
        private var loader:Loader;

        private var asset:AssetManager;
        private var starling:Starling;

        private function debug(... arguments):void {
            if (Worker.current.isPrimordial) {
                trace("Master[1] : " + arguments);
            } else {
                trace("Worker[" + Worker.current.getSharedProperty("worker") + "] : " + arguments);
            }
        }

        public function SlaveWorker(mosi_:MessageChannel, miso_:MessageChannel, byteArray_:ByteArray) {

            Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
            Security.allowDomain("*");

            Security.allowInsecureDomain(Security.pageDomain);
            Security.allowDomain(Security.pageDomain);

            debug(Security.sandboxType);
            miso = miso_;
            mosi = mosi_;
            byteArray = byteArray_;

            //asset = new AssetManager();
            mosi.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onMosi);
            //asset = new AssetManager();
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
            loader = new Loader();
        }

        private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
            //starling = new Starling(Inutil, this.stage);
        }

        private var archiveType:String;
        private var archiveName:String;

        private function onMosi(evt:Event):void {
            var command:* = mosi.receive();
            debug(command);
            if (command is String) {
                if (command == "loadArchive") {

                    var type:* = mosi.receive();
                    var archive:* = mosi.receive();

                    debug(type);

                    debug(archive);

                    if (type == "texture") {
                        archiveType = type;
                        archiveName = archive;
                        var _sair:Boolean = false;
                        while (!_sair) {
                            var pos:int = archiveName.search("/");
                            if (pos < 0)
                                _sair = true;
                            else
                                archiveName = archiveName.slice(pos + 1);
                            debug(archiveName);
                        }
                        archiveName = archiveName.slice(0, archiveName.search(".") - 1);
                        debug("arquivo a carregar " + archive);
                        var lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
                        lc.checkPolicyFile = false;

                        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onArchiveLoaded);

                        //asset.enqueue(archive);
                        //asset.loadQueue(onArchiveLoaded);
                        loader.load(new URLRequest(archive), lc);
                        debug("lol");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private function onArchiveLoaded(e:Event):void {
            var _loader:Loader = e as Loader;
            //if (value == 1.0) {
            debug("carregado " + _loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesLoaded + " bytes");
            if (archiveType == "texture") {
                //var texture:Texture = asset.get
                debug("data type" + _loader.contentLoaderInfo.contentType);
                byteArray.clear();
                //byteArray.writeObject(asset.getTexture(archiveName));
                var bitmapData:BitmapData = _loader.content as BitmapData;
                byteArray.writeObject(Texture.fromBitmapData(bitmapData));
                miso.send("STATUS");
                miso.send("COMPLETE");
            }
            //}
        }
    }

}
```

**-EDIT**
forgot to say 
already give worker giveAppPrivileges flag
var bgWorker:Worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(swfBytes, true);

Comment: Why do you use a worker to load data? This is already asynchronous, maybe you should try loading with main SWF. Also, the error states that your worker class is running in another sandbox than main app and does not have local file system access, IIRC this should be fixed by loading in main class and not by altering sandbox for worker.

Comment: because i will do a heavy processing with de image in the worker, the main app will not use the image, only the result, and i dont want to spend time with the image transfer to occupy the main app processing time.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your error message, maybe you can fix using the giveAppPrivileges flag.

```
public function createWorker(swf:ByteArray, giveAppPrivileges:Boolean = false):Worker
```

giveAppPrivileges:Boolean (default = false) — indicates whether the worker should be given application sandbox privileges in AIR. This parameter is ignored in Flash Player.

Comment: already did that, var bgWorker:Worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(swfBytes, true);