# AS3 - How to load local file inside the worker?

Tags: actionscript-3, security, loader, worker

The same issue is described in [using loader with worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114114/) e.g., but IMHO that question contains too much info and still has no answer.

As I can see, the main reason is in sandbox mode of the worker SWF - it's always ***remote***, while the main SWF's one is ***localTrusted***. That's why I'm unable to use even simple URLLoaders, getting "*Error #2148 SWF file A cannot access local resource B. Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources*".  I've tried some obvious things alike the

```
-use-network=false
```

but it changes nothing.

Is there any way to handle it?

Comment: I wonder why offloading a `Loader` into a worker, loading is already asynchronous. Consider loading in parent and then providing the resultant `ByteArray` to the worker.

Comment: Looks like it's a common question for a common appoach.) I simply load data in the thread where it will be processed. E.g. I have a 3D-model loaded by some 3D-engine. Normally it will load all the linked textures etc. by itself (implicitly) and due to the described issue I get an additional headache.

Comment: @VyacheslavOrlovsky Did you ever figure this one out? I've got the same issue, I can't reference my loader.content to draw bitmaps in my worker.